# Not able to fetch register values using Mike M's BCM2835 C code

Tags: c, c++, gcc

I'm attempting to utilize the `bcm2835_peri_read(uint32_t*)` function from Mike M's BCM2835 code, however console-output-debugging indicates I'm continually getting back my address.  I'm using `g++` on the Pi itself... specifically:

```
sync
g++ registertest.c -lbcm2835 -lcurses -lpthread -o Listen
```

...where `registertest.c` is my own code file - the relevant bit is on Pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/vGkdVs3n) and here:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

// snip

byte getByte() {
        volatile uint32_t flagAddr = bscSlaveAddr + 0x10;  // bscSlaveAddr = 0x7E214000
        uint32_t flagRegi = bcm2835_peri_read(&flagAddr);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&screenLock);
        mvprintw(2, 20, "Flag: %8X", flagRegi);  // Always reads 7E214010
        refresh();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&screenLock);

        while((flagRegi >> 1) & 1) { // While the FIFO Queue is empty...
                usleep(1000); // Wait.
                uint32_t flagRegi = bcm2835_peri_read(&flagAddr);

                pthread_mutex_lock(&screenLock);
                mvprintw(2, 20, "Flag: %8X", flagRegi);
                refresh();
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&screenLock);
        }
        volatile uint32_t dataAddr = bscSlaveAddr;
        uint32_t dataRegi = bcm2835_peri_read(&dataAddr);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&screenLock);
        mvprintw(2, 40, "Data: %8X", dataRegi);  // Always reads 7E214000
        refresh();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&screenLock);
        return dataRegi && 0xFF; // Get the value, then spit back just the data.
}
```

I compiled and installed Mike's code as was instructed on his website.  Is there something I'm messing up?

Comment: Is this a Pi 2 or one of the other models?  Also, actually including a relevant snippet of `registertest.c` here would be beneficial.

Comment: @goldilocks This would be on a Pi B+.

Comment: @goldilocks Added the method that accesses the register.

Comment: @goldilocks Reading through Mike's source seems to indicate that if the `__arm__` `#define` variable isn't set, just return the address given because we're not on the BCM2835.  However, I'd've assume it _is_ set because we're on the Pi B+...

Comment: So I get a seg  fault in `peri_write` for that SSCCE too.

Comment: @goldilocks Mike's code doesn't `mmap` to the BSC Slave area of the BCM2835, which is why it failed.  Completely scrapping his code let me `mmap` the areas myself and working through that.  [Circle](https://github.com/rsta2/circle) was a great help in figuring things out - especially [i2cslave.cpp](https://github.com/rsta2/circle/blob/master/lib/i2cslave.cpp) - so I got it to work completely as intended now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bcm2835_peri_read](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/group__lowlevel.html#ga5f242135f5088f8c319492426a1ed5e3) documentation may be wrong or just misleading.

Try passing the address you want to read rather than a pointer to the address.

e.g. change

> uint32_t flagRegi = bcm2835_peri_read(&flagAddr);

to

> uint32_t flagRegi = bcm2835_peri_read(flagAddr);

---

EDITED TO ADD

The following code reads and displays the value of the 16 BSC/SPI slave registers.  Use PI_2_PERI on a Pi2.

```
/*
   bscs.c
   2015-03-30
   Public Domain
*/

/*
   gcc -o bscs bscs.c
   sudo ./bscs
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define PI_1_PERI 0x20000000
#define PI_2_PERI 0x3F000000

static volatile uint32_t piPeriphBase = PI_1_PERI;

#define BSCS_BASE  (piPeriphBase + 0x214000)

#define BSCS_LEN  0x40

static volatile uint32_t  *bscsReg = MAP_FAILED;

/* Map in registers. */

static uint32_t * initMapMem(int fd, uint32_t addr, uint32_t len)
{
    return (uint32_t *) mmap(0, len,
       PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC,
       MAP_SHARED|MAP_LOCKED,
       fd, addr);
}

int gpioInitialise(void)
{
   int fd;

   fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC) ;

   if (fd < 0)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,
         "This program needs root privileges.  Try using sudo\n");
      return -1;
   }

   bscsReg  = initMapMem(fd, BSCS_BASE,  BSCS_LEN);

   close(fd);

   if (bscsReg == MAP_FAILED)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Bad, mmap failed\n");
      return -1;
   }
   return 0;
}

main()
{
   int i;

   if (gpioInitialise() < 0) return 1;

   for (i=0; i<16; i++)
   {
      printf("reg=%d val=%8X\n",
         i, bscsReg[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Removing the ampersands and adding asterisks (to more closely mimic the code that Mike has in, say, `bcm2835_gpio_lev`) now starts giving me a segfault.  I'm trying to pin down where.

Comment: I don't think the docs are wrong,  but if "misleading" == "prone to misinterpretation" then there you go.  Did you try exactly what I suggested?

Comment: @joan @goldilocks I believe I've tracked the segfault.  It most likely has something to do with a call to `bcm2835_peri_write`, using a pointer to an address in memory (as goldilocks's answer indicates it should be).  `volatile uint32_t* configAddr = bscSlaveAddr + 0xC; bcm2835_peri_write(configAddr, 0x205);`

Comment: Why aren't you just using `gdb` for this?

Comment: Minibian doesn't have `gdb` by default, and I'm having a fun time installing new packages due to a firewall that I can't administrate.  At least I have another Pi that was manually let through... I should probably get it.

Comment: Bugger.  `(gdb) bt` after the segfault points towards `bcm2835.c:184`, which starts off `__asm__`.

Comment: [Looks to me](https://github.com/matthiasbock/bcm2835/blob/master/src/bcm2835.c) like that's a call to `_peri_write`.   You should try and come up with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), there's a lot of extraneous stuff going on in your snippet, what with the ncurses and threading and such.

Comment: I'd already tried removing ncurses and pthread from the mix to try to diagnose what the heck is going on.  I've produced one [SSCCE](http://pastebin.com/Z2ZZvQJF) and placed it on Pastebin - I've tried both `0x20214000` and `0x7E214000` as my BSC Slave peripheral address - physical and bus, respectively.  If there's anything else that's needed, I'm on [The Bakery](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery) as well.

Comment: "Removing the ampersands and adding asterisks"?  Why did you start adding asterisks.  Just pass the address you want to read to peri_read.

Comment: @joan I did not declare variables like `configAddr` as pointers, just straight values.  I added asterisks to make them pointers.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter in this case, it's just a bad habit not to use the correct type.  If the size of the type differs from the address size and you are supposed to use a pointer, that could cause a segfault.  But of course this is a `uint32_t` and the pi uses 32-bit addresses, so that's not an issue.   Bad form though anyway ;) If it's supposed to be a pointer, it should be a pointer.   I should be able to test your SSCCE this evening sometime.

Comment: @goldilocks Any chance you figured out what's going wrong?

Comment: I'm actually under a little stress right now because of a midnight 3/31 deadline -- but free as a bird tomorrow.

Comment: It's no big deal.  Was able to at least poke at `gdb`, having it print `*paddr`.  Reported back that it couldn't read the memory at that location.  Any hints how that gets fixed?

Comment: If you had just done what I told you to do in  the first place you could have read the contents of the address.  The chances of being able to achieve what you want (I2C slave) with the BSC/SPI slave peripheral are slim.  I'd stick to the bit bang route.

Comment: @joan There isn't a need to be so snappy.  While I appreciate your code - it indeed runs - I want to make sure that the memory barriers that were provided in Mike's code are used for maximum safety.  Additionally, going down the bit-bang route, reading raw from the pins, has proven pretty much impossible; the Pi doesn't register anything at all on the data line.

Comment: @sctjkc01 I hope other contributors realise you are now trying to solve an unrelated unspecified problem.  It certainly was not apparent to me that you'd tried the code I suggested and it worked.  But I'm talking about the original one character change.

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever used that library to enable i2c-0, but I'm gonna concur with joan here.  Look:

```
uint32_t bcm2835_peri_read(volatile uint32_t* paddr)
{
    if (debug)
    { [...] }
    else
    {
    // Make sure we dont return the _last_ read which might get lost
    // if subsequent code changes to a different peripheral
    uint32_t ret = *paddr;
    *paddr; // Read without assigning to an unused variable
    return ret;
    }
}
```

The "read" here is just dereferencing an address, which is how pointers normally work.<sup>1</sup>

```
int x = 5;
int *p = &x;
int n = *p;
```

Guess what `n` equals?  5, which is why you keep getting your argument back.  But `p` itself has a different value, which is the memory address of `x`.  Dereferencing `p` yields the value at that address, which is 5.  That's *reading* the value at `p`.

Hence ditch the `&` and **make `flagAddr` a pointer**:

```
    volatile uint32_t *flagAddr = bscSlaveAddr + 0x10;  // bscSlaveAddr = 0x7E214000
    uint32_t flagRegi = bcm2835_peri_read(flagAddr);
```

Make sense?  What you want to do is specify the address for a pointer, which is normally not a hardcoded value but a more abstract reference (e.g. `&x` is address by reference).  What you were doing is specifying the address as a value and then passing the address of that value.

---

<sup>1. I'm guessing the second, discarded `*paddr`, has to do with whatever protocol/mechanism is at play -- note and consider the `volatile`....</sup>